# What does "Module {path}\src\app\sales\models\index.ts has no static exports" mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-3

We've just added webpack 3.0.0 to our angular 2 project. I had it working, got about a 20-25% performance improvement and a 50% (ish) decrease in size. I then rebased this onto the main branch and started to get the error.

```
ERROR in chunk main [initial]
[name].bundle.js
Module \src\app\sales\models\index.ts has no static exports true
```

**What does that error actually mean?** I haven't been able to find anything useful online. **Any tips on fixing it?**

The `\src\app\sales\models\index.ts` file hasn't changed since my commit and only contains:

```
export * from './app-state';
export * from './purchase.model';
export * from './base.model';
export * from './view-state.model';
export * from './address';
export * from './core';
export * from './cover';
export * from './disclaimers';
export * from './family';
export * from './premium';
export * from './payments';
export * from './policy';
export * from './tracking.model';
```

After undoing my initial rebase I rebased the main on branch on top of my work and then found the commit that "broke" webpack (thank goodness for `git bisect`) and I'm in the process of slowly walking the changes back in to see if I can keep it working.

Looking at the webpack source the error is being thrown [ConcatenatedModule.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/optimize/ConcatenatedModule.js#L477) in `HarmonyImportSpecifierDependencyConcatenatedTemplate`

```
    if(!Array.isArray(module.providedExports))
        throw new Error(`Module ${module.resource} has no static exports ${module.providedExports}`);
```

Some poking around has shown that `module.providedExports` is a boolean with a value of `true`, hence the error; however, I've not been able to workout what sets that value.

What does the error mean? Other debugging tips?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. I don't know why this error is throws but i have fix it in replace '*' by explicit export.

for example :

before :

```
export * from './foo';
export * from './bar';
```

after :

```
export {Foo1, Foo2, /*...*/} from './foo';
export {Bar1, Bar2, /*...*/} from './bar'
```